# Jquery ui autocomplete combobox error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I used the Jquery ui  autocomplete combobox http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox 
I have used the same script given on the page. The combobox is working perfectly. Except when the page size grows and scroll bars appear, and we try to move the scroll bars the toggle button is moving with scroll. So, i tried changing position attribute to relative and also absolute in ui-combobox-toggle class. Still it is not working

This is how the html is rendered (from firebug) before hover on toggle button. After hover ui-state-hover class is added and the toggle button is falling into its place. It is working fine in firefox but in internet explorer the togglebutton is initially moving with scroll and then falling into its place when hovered

```
 <span class="ui-combobox">
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ddlQuestionShortDescription_2_txtInput" class="ui-state-default ui-combobox-input ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
<a class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle" style="position: relative;" tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text"></span>
</a>
</span>
```

Comment: how does your html look? can you create a reduced set of code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us the problem?

Comment: I was not able to add entire code. I added the html from firebug html view